# Make Label Straight using AWCollectionViewDialLayout – Cocoa Controls

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using AWCollectionViewDialLayout demo provided on git below is the link:- https://github.com/awdigital/AWCollectionViewDialLayout
I want to make labels straight. 
Please Help.
[image]

Comment: what you have tried? and explain your requirement.

Comment: Hello Dharmesh above screenshot I want to make all labels straight.

Comment: just labels? rotating images are ok? have a look at layer transformations

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example, your cell itself is rotated, not just the label. So you cannot only make the label straight and keep the image rotated.

If you still wants to make both element straight, take a look on the [source file](https://github.com/awdigital/AWCollectionViewDialLayout/blob/master/AWCollectionViewDialLayoutDemo/AWCollectionViewDialLayout.m) of the libarary. You are looking for variable called `rotationT`
 on line 181. Just keep its value to 0 and have a try

Comment: Thank you very much Fangming.